# Python: How to embed my python script into a webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x, embed

I have a full website with HTML and need to add an interactive piece that I could easily write with python (or even c/c++). What can I can use/do to accomplish this? The script will take user input do some calculations and display the output. I am completely lost on where to start, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to embed Python into a html file using <py-script> tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- linking to PyScript assets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Put Python code inside the the <py-script> tag -->
    <py-script>
        print("Hello World!")
        input("Enter your name:")
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another way could be to embed Python script as a child process (eg: in Node.js):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

var child = spawn("python", ["-c",`
print("Hi")
print(int(input("Enter a number:")))
`]);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
child.on('exit', () => process.exit());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed Python in your HTML page the you will have to use a Python based web server which will have HTML form for data input and execute provided Python code as server side script and return you the desired result.
You could start by using Django.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a web application with python back-end, then you need to do with a web  framework, like **Django** or **Flask**. **Flask** is more easy to use and understandable for beginning level.

**Jinja2 is a popular templating engine for Python. A web templating system combines a template with a certain data source to render dynamic web pages.**

Flask code:

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> My First Try Using Flask </h1>
    <p> Flask is Fun </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**For Run Your First App:**

```
python3 app.py
```